# Get data from server using of AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my program a number of values are stored on the server.
I read these data using of the `AsyncTask` class from the server.

**This is my code:**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static List<String> mPackName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPackName = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            boolean check = new GetDataAsyncTask().execute("1234567").get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            final String mCode = params[0];

            APIGettingPosts apiGettingPosts = new APIGettingPosts(TestActivity.this, "get_off_code.php");
            apiGettingPosts.getOffCode(new APIGettingPosts.OnOffCodeReceived() {
                @Override
                public void onReceived(List<Posts> posts) {
                    if (!(posts == null || posts.isEmpty()))
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); ++i) {
                            mPackName.add(posts.get(i).getTitle());
                            Log.e("mPackName["+String.valueOf(i)+"]",mPackName.get(i));
                        }
                }
            });
            Log.e("Size of mPackName: ", String.valueOf(mPackName.size()));

            for (int i = 0; i < mPackName.size(); ++i)
                if (mCode.equals(mPackName.get(i))) {
                    Log.e("Is Equal: ", mPackName.get(i));
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The program correctly receives the data from the server and stores it in the `mPackName` list. At the end of the `doInBackground` function, the program checks if the input value in the `GetDataAsyncTask().execute("1234567")` function exists in the `mPackName` list, returns the `true` value.

Although the input value of the  `GetDataAsyncTask().execute("1234567")` function is in the `mPackName`list, the program returns the `false` value.

The `Log cat` output is as follows:

> 08-28/com.green E/Size of mPackName:: 0
>
> 08-28/com.green E/mPackName[0]: 1234567
>
> 08-28/com.green E/mPackName[1]: QAZXSWE
>
> 08-28/com.green E/mPackName[2]: QWERTYU

The size of the `mPackName` list is also zero in `Log cat` , although it has three values `{'1234567','QAZXSWE','QWERTYU'}`.

**The question is:** How do I search '1234567' value in the `mPackName` list to return the `true` value in `check = new GetDataAsyncTask().execute("1234567").get();`
code?

Comment: I think in the _doInBackground_ method, the program is not compiled linearly.
Since in the  _doInBackground_ method, we are waiting for the data from the server. The size of 0 of list is first seen and the program waits for the whole data to be called from the server.

Comment: Yes and no... yes doInBackground does run on a background thread but I'm guessing APIGettingPosts apiGettingPosts = new APIGettingPosts(...) is also running on a separate background thread. So your log statement is executing before onReceived has been called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Edited Answer

Looks like you even don't need `AsyncTask` as `getOffCode` method already runs in **background thread**.

Remove `GetDataAsyncTask` class and create a method like below.

```
private void search(final SearchCallback callback) {
    APIGettingPosts apiGettingPosts = new APIGettingPosts(TestActivity.this, "get_off_code.php");
    apiGettingPosts.getOffCode(new APIGettingPosts.OnOffCodeReceived() {
        @Override
        public void onReceived(List<Posts> posts) {
            if (!(posts == null || posts.isEmpty())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); ++i) {
                    mPackName.add(posts.get(i).getTitle());
                    Log.e("mPackName[" + String.valueOf(i) + "]", mPackName.get(i));
                    if (mCode.equals(mPackName.get(i))) {
                        callback.onSearchFound(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            callback.onSearchFound(false);
        }
    });
}

public interface SearchCallback{
    void onSearchFound(boolean success);
}
```

Then call from onCreate method like below

```
search(new SearchCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onSearchFound(boolean success) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Krishna. you're awesome.

Comment: @Saeed Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a switch in the onPostExecute() method.

EG.

```
...

private class GetDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

@Override
void onPostExecute(Object o){
    handleResults()
}

...

void handleResults(){
// Insert your check here
}
```

Comment: On post execute is called after your execute method finishes. If this does not work, there is something else wrong.

You might check out this wonderful write up https://stackoverflow.com/a/12575319/2104990

It explains how to get information from your AsyncTask properly